# Web-service-API to administrate Exchange-Accounts

Tags: c#, web-services, exchange-server

Is there a web-service-API that I can use to administrate the accounts on an exchange-server 2010 (update to 2013 is possible)?

What I have found so far:

ECP (Exchange Control Panel): While offering all the intended funcationality, this does not seem to offer webservices, but only a browser-frontend. I was hoping to get around browser-scraping.

EWS (Exchange Web Services): While being a webservice, this seems to offer standard-client-functions only and nothing to administrate the accounts themselves.

Any suggestions?

A managed C#-API would be nice...

Answer (score 0):

I did not find webservices to do this, but the ExchangePowerShell instead.
For this to work, you need to install the Exchange Management Tools (e.g. as explained here http://exchangeserverpro.com/exchange-2010-install-management-tools/) and a reference to System.Management.Automation.dll (available via NuGet).

And to get you started, please find the code I used as Proof of Concept below.

```
WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("http://{HostnameOfExchangeServer}/powershell"), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", (PSCredential) null);
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create()) {
    powershell.AddCommand("Get-MailboxServer");
    runspace.Open();
    powershell.Runspace = runspace;
    return powershell.Invoke();
}
```

Since PSCredential is set to null, normal windows authentication is used.